# vhosts migration from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4

Tags: virtualhost

I am moving from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 on Solaris 11.3.  I have used Solaris Package Manager to install packages.

I have had good success using vhosts.conf on 2.2 and so tried copying my vhosts.conf to the /etc/apache2/2.4/conf.d

In order to save space I used a link to link /var/apache2/2.2/htdocs to /var/apache2/2.4/htdocs

preliminary tests done by browsing localhost/htdocs_folder_name showed the correct web pages.

I have since modified the hosts.conf in order to get it working, and have had many error messages.

System recommended using ./apachectl -S to get some help.  Not very helpful!

I used the following format in 2.2...  supposedly this should work in 2.4  here are two samples... there are 25 total, 12 pairs, +1

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/apache2/2.2/htdocs/crete
    ServerName nc-concrete.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/apache2/2.2/htdocs/crete
    ServerName www.nc-concrete.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts files are provided by a linking the 2.2 http folder to 2.4  This shouldn't cause any problems...

Help!

Comment: Please share your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Oh how dumb I feel...  Noticed that the 2nd vhost entry for www.domain.com was included all in one.  Once corrected... I had it licked.  The best part was being able to use my Apache word processor to make the text file, then move it to the conf.d folder

Noticed that the big security deal in Apache2.4 is that unless you list a folder in vhosts.conf, you cannot access it.  Not that it was ever a problem to protect folders.  Just added a index.html file that said Forbidden.  Keept prying eyes out of the folders.

If you are having issues and want help, email me...

Dave